# Implementing Tensorflow Regression Model on Basketball data

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, regression

I am following along the following guide to tensorflow regression models: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_regression

Using basketball data. I am wanting to predict NBA career length based on college stats. I currently have normalized data in the format:

[image]

I then build the following model based on the code in the above link:

```
def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                       input_shape=(train.shape[1],)),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001)

  model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae'])
  return model

model = build_model()
model.summary()
```

Which appears to work fine. However when I then try to run the model and record the history using the following code:

```
EPOCHS = 200

labels = ['Age','G','FG','FGA','X3P','X3PA','FTA','TRB','AST','STL','BLK','Wt','final_ht','colyears','nbayears']

# Store training stats
history = model.fit(train, labels, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_split=0.2, verbose=0)
```

This gives me an error that: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim', which I am having trouble understanding what it means. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: when you fit the model your ```labels``` parameter should be the true outcome of your ```train``` data, not the labels list as you use in this example.

Comment: Ah meaning the NBA years value and the normalized data shouldn't have that in the dataframe?

Comment: the first parameter of the fit function should be an array with each element of the array representing one row of your dataframe that contains the normalized data that is expected to predict the NBA career length. The second parameter should be a one-dimensional array containing the actual value of NBA career length (target variable) for each respective row/element in the dataframe/array you specified in the first parameter. I'll post an answer real quick so you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `.fit` function of the model the second parameter should represent your target variable (NBA career length). This will be a one-dimensional array instead of the list you tried to pass to the function.

This should solve the problem.